# Attraction of matter in curved spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, reference-frames, curvature

Is there still going be a force between them (converging space which makes the two bodies meet together at a point)if both of them are absolute rest with respect any frame of reference.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why would there *not* be a force?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GR gravitation is due to curved spacetime, not just curved space. So even though they are at rest in space, they are still “moving” through time. As you go along their worldlines their time direction will start to curve in towards each other resulting in gravitational attraction.

Comment: but how can a body move only in a direction of time

Comment: sir your answere was pretty brief i could not get it , sir is there any way that i can contact you personally so that i can clear my douts./ dale

Comment: This site isn’t really designed for extended discussions. You might want to try another website.

Comment: may be we can chat

Comment: how can body move only in direction of time

Answer (score -1):

In the general relativity, the force is not a mater of attracting of two objects, but the curvature of spacetime due to energy-matter distribution through the fabric of spacetime, makes the objects move trough the curve as a geodesic around the massive object which curves the spacetime fabric.In this case no gravity.